# HTML / CSS: Have image with text on it in flex. But after hover, I want text to change and linear gradient black transparent from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling a day now. been watching video and reading but still can not wrap my head around how to manage it.

The problem is:

There is a flex parent.

2 children that shares 50 % width of the screen each.
height is 200px.

Inside the children I am adding image with text on top of it and with white transparent color ontop as a layer.
I have designed it in adobe xd. Inserting picture of 1 flex children with image & text on it here: [before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4ZS.png)

After i hover, i want it to create a linear-grade where there is dark on top and more transparent at the bottom. On the dark side, i want text to appear.
Here is the second picture from adobe XD when I hover: [when hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VczhC.png)

There is a href on the image.

So how would I solve this problem? Could someone come with a example code?

I have tried to code it. I kinda did manage to have text hover, but you guys probably have easier and better way coding it.

Would appreciate all the help i can get. Been sitting hours with this.

---

**UPDATE: MORE DETAILED**

Okey posting the code here:

also here is XD file of the project i am building. if you hover ur mouse over where it says MEN and WOMAN, you will see the effect i am trying to achive.
[Adobe XD file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4ZS.png)

here is netlify of what i have done: [https://hopeful-booth-b5fbb7.netlify.app/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VczhC.png)
you will see alot of boxes, thats just layout created so i can build on them.
you can already see the image is a bit off, but i have kinda managed the text hover.

The code is kinda mess, that's why I preferred it to be built :-/

you can inspect the code to have better overview i guess.

Html:
Section inside main.

```
<section class="one">
    <div class="box4">
      <a href="#" class="link__men-jacket"
        ><span class="text">
          <h1>Click here to go to mens jacket</h1>
        </span>
        <img
          src="img/Men-Style-in-Monsoon.jpg"
          alt="New-Men-Jackets"
          class="new__men--img"
        />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="box5"></div>
  </section>
```

CSS file:

```
.one {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
}
 .box4 {
 background-color: indianred;
 height: 200px;
 width: 50%;
}

 .new__men--img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  }

  .link__men-jacket {
   position: absolute;
  }

  .link__men-jacket .text {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.8s ease;
   }

  .link__men-jacket .text h1 {
   margin: 0;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   }

   .link__men-jacket:hover .text {
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    }


    .box5 {
     background-color: lemonchiffon;
     height: 200px;
     width: 50%;
     grid-area: box5;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you didn't add your code to the post, i can't come up with an example code. I can try to help if you add it.

Do you want something like this?

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.example{
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.hover{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128,128,128, 0.8), rgba(0,0,0, 0.8));
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 8;
}

.hover:hover {
  opacity: 100;
}

.hover:hover h2{
  opacity: 100;
}

.hover:hover + #white{
  opacity: 0;
}

h2 {
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
}

#white{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 4;
}

h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* these lines centers text*/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="example">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/573/500/200.jpg?hmac=QeNNKNuQ4NM0IWz7poy375InmsefvVgUgluVaO2JyUc" alt="">
      <div class="hover">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="white">
          <h1>LOREM</h1>
      </div>
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I posted more detailed information about the problem i wish to solve

Comment: Please post a complete answer here, not on a third party site

Comment: Okay,I just added a snippet to my answer.

Comment: @woxel omg this is actually what I was looking for! I will add it to my code and see if I manage it to work. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask if you have any further questions